# Angular 2/Ionic 2 ngModel Dynamic Global Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi everyone I currently am attempting to use my ngModeled variable globally.

So far I have the following code snippet.

homepage.html

```
<ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="databaseID">
```

homepage.ts

```
public databaseID;
```

These functions work and when I attempt to print the ngModeled data from the home.ts class it prints what has been entered by the user. However I am not sure how to call databaseID from another class.  I have tried setting databaseID to global (globals are static and therefor this will not work).

Could you possibly explain a way that I may access this variable from a different class?

Some possible thoughts I had were dependency injection and using a providers. But I'm not sure what would be the best way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to share a variable between different components/directives is to use a service.  What you can do is bind the ngModel directly to a service, and then access the service from multiple components.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    databaseId: string;

    constructor() {
        this.databaseId = "1234";
    }
}
```

Component:

```
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="myService.databaseID">
```

Services Tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Dependency Injection: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to call databaseID from another class

Do the other classes need to execute some logic when the `databaseID` changes?  If so, use an Observable or a Subject in a service.  The other classes would `subscribe()` to the Observable to be notified of changes.  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service for an example.  (Even though it is an example of using a service to communicate between an parent and child, the same technique applies to communication between any two components.)

If you don't need to execute any logic, then the answer provided by @Brandyn is good.  However, I would not directly use the service property name in the view/template of a component.  Instead, I would use a component property or a  "get" [accessor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors):

```
@Component({
   template: `<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="database.id">`
})
export class HomePageComponent {
    constructor(private _dbService: DatabaseService) { }
    get database() { return this._dbService.database; }
}
```

```
export class DatabaseService {
    database: { id: 0 }; 
}
```

You might want to define an interface for the database type, if it has a number of properties:

```
export interface Database {
    id: number;
    // other properties here
}
```

Then

```
get database(): Database { return this._dbService.database; }
```